# clear javascript. dynamically created div resize: it only grow! why?

Tags: javascript, css, html, resize

First off, the whole code is [here, on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ubETN9dN).

**No `jquery` or alikes are employed!**

I have a HTML with a `DIV` created using `document.createElement("div")` and plugged into the page with `document.getElementById('p').appendChild(d);`

The new `DIV` is provided with a bunch of event handlers:

```js
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.className = 'rect';
d.addEventListener('mousedown', catch_box, false);
d.addEventListener('mouseup', release_box, false);
d.addEventListener('mouseout', release_box, false);
d.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse_move_box, false);
d.addEventListener(wheel_hook, scroll_box, false);
document.getElementById('p').appendChild(d);
```

This works fine:

```
// move the box around on 'mousemove'
var lPos = cache.left + m_speed * cache.h_dir,
    tPos = cache.top + m_speed * cache.v_dir,
    ok = (lPos >= 0) && ((lPos + cache.width) <= max_width) &&
         (tPos >= 0) && ((tPos + cache.height) <= max_height);
if (ok) {
    box.style.left = lPos + 'px';
    box.style.top = tPos + 'px';
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
// resize the box
var hSize = cache.width + s_speed * cache.h_dir,
    vSize = cache.height + s_speed * cache.v_dir,
    ok = (hSize >= min_width) &&
         ((cache.left + hSize) <= max_width) &&
         (vSize >= min_height) &&
         ((cache.top + vSize) <= max_height);
if (ok) {
    box.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+hSize+'px;height:'+vSize+'px;');
    box.style.width = hSize + 'px';
    box.style.height = vSize + 'px';
}
```

The `box.style.width` and `box.style.height` may only grow :(

**The question is:** WHY?? And how to work it around?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you want to happen, and what happens instead? (And why, in that code setting the width and height, have you got both that `setAttribute()` call *and* the two lines to set width and height?)

Comment: I want to resize (and move) that `DIV`.
The motion works fine (i.e. assignments to `.left` and `.top` work).
But resize can only enlarge `DIV`'s size...

I have a debug trace in a `<textarea>` and can see **negative** increments, but I get only larger `DIV` :(

And when it hits the size limit, the motion fails too...

Comment: [screenshot at imgur](http://i.imgur.com/yM02ZrW.png)